# Is NPM - node-soap support WsHttpBinding?

Tags: node.js, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I am getting an error status code 415 while calling a method written in WCF service. Later identified this error caused because of the default protocol used in WCF service is WsHttpBinding.

After altering the config to BasicHttpBinding, response are started getting successfully, but from the security aspect which is not right way to handle this.

[NPM Package link](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

Is there any option to support WsHttpBinding from this soap client?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who can answer if WsHttpBinding is supported for node-soap clients ?

I read:
"As WsHttpBinding is built using WS-* specifications, it does not support wider ranges of clients and it cannot be consumed by older .NET versions less than 3 version"

source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind